# can I upgrade my laptop M.2 SSD

Tags: hardware-rec, m.2

I have a  Msi GE62 6QD Apache Pro with the following specifications
Ram: 16gb 
Storage:128 M.2 SSD GB+ 1tb HDD
GPU: Intel Graphic Card+ Nvidia 960m
Cpu: Intel Core i7 6700K Display: 15.6 FHD LED

I would like to ask a question of which is can i upgrade the m.2 ssd from 128gb to 256Gb+, I would like to choose this version of m.2 ssd
https://amzn.com/B0194MV300 https://amzn.com/B01639694M

And how can I know if a certain M.2 SSD is compatible with my machine?

Comment: Please take the time to make your question readable.  If you are listing parts, present it as a list, so it can be read.

Answer (score 1):

Both the [ScanDisk X400](https://www.sandisk.com/business/computing/x400) and the [Samsung 950 PRO](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/memory-storage/MZ-V5P512BW) are indeed compatible with the [GE62 6QD APACHE PRO](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GE62-6QD-APACHE-PRO.html#hero-specification)

ScanDisk X400 Specificatins:
[image]

GE62 6QD APACHE PRO Specifications:
[image]

Samsung 950 PRO Specifications:
[image]